# Where are the Ant libraries in an IntelliJ IDEA Mac installation?

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I want to same setting Windows8 and Mac.

but i cant.

I was finished IntelliJ Ant setting on Windows8 that maverick-ant.jar, jarkarta. common-ant.jar...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.1\lib\ant\lib"

but I can not find Ant Directory on mac.

please let me know that.

Answer (score 1):

/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE/Contents/lib/ant/lib